# Fetch data from API depending on the components props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problems figuring out how to setup the structure where to the fetch data depending on what the props.catergory value is in my PodcastList component and set state

I could fetch the data in my parent component (Home.js), set the state and pass the state as props. But the API endpoint need to take in an categoryId, I cant fetch all podcasts at once.. Thats why I made a child component that takes in and categoryId. Like this:

`<PodcastList category='1301' />`

And my tought was to do the fetch in the child component passing this.props.category to the api endpoint. (I accutally dont know what im doing)

Can someone help explain how to accomplish what I want?

My code looks like this:

**Home.js component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { fetchPopularPodcasts } from './api'
import PodcastList from './PodcastList'

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <PodcastList category='1301' /> // Lists all Podcasts from category: Arts
        <PodcastList category='1303' /> // Lists all Podcasts from category: Comedy
        <PodcastList category='1304' /> // Lists all Podcasts from category: Educationrts
        <PodcastList category='1305' /> // Lists all Podcasts from category: Kids & Family
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**PodcastList.js component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { fetchPodcastCategory } from './api'

export default class PodcastList extends Component {

    state = {
    podcasts: [],
    loading: true,
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    const podcasts = await fetchPodcastCategory(this.props.categoryId);
      this.setState({
            podcasts,
            loading: false,
        })
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-md-12'>
                {category.map((pod) => {
                  return (
                            <div className='pod-box'>
                                {pod.Title}
                                {pod.Label}
                            </div>
                )
                })}
                </div>
            </div>
      )
    }
}


export default PodcastList;
```

**Api.js**

```
import Feed from 'feed-to-json-promise'

export async function fetchPopularPodcasts () {
  const response = await fetch('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=podcast&country=se&media=podcast&entity=podcast&limit=200')
  const podcasts = await response.json()

  return podcasts.results
}

export async function fetchPodcastCategory (categoryId) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/se/rss/toppodcasts/limit=100/genre=${categoryId}/explicit=true/json`)
  const podcasts = await response.json()

  return podcasts.feed
}

export async function fetchPodcast (podId) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=${podId}&country=se`)
  const podcasts = await response.json()

  return podcasts.results
}

export async function fetchPodcastEpisodes (feedUrl) {
  const feed = new Feed()
  const episodes = await feed.load(feedUrl)

  return episodes
}
```

Comment: could you explain the question a bit, you want do another api call based on the value of podcasts from fetchPodcastCategory(this.props.categoryId),
also you are using this.props.categoryId but passing only category in props

Comment: in my PodcastList components that I render in my parent component, that takes in a props called category, I somehow want to fetch data from the API endpoint I have maked, based on the value of props.category

Comment: you can do that thing the way you have done

Answer (score 0):

I would do that inside podcastlist component, if you want data back to parent component you can run a callback,

give a function to podcastlist as a prop and run that function like this,

const podcasts = await fetchPodcastCategory(this.props.categoryId);
      this.setState({
            podcasts,
            loading: false,
        },this.props.callback(podcasts))
  }

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your design is all too bad.

Basically if you change

```
 {category.map((pod) => {
```

with

```
 {this.state.podcasts.map((pod) => {
```

this code should work.

What are you trying to accomplish exactly and why is this architecture not doing it for you? If you clarify this you can get a better answer.